# How to reuse Magento2 <head> block

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, magento-2.1, html

I want to use the features of [default_head_blocks.xml](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css) in a custom block that will not be rendered for output, but saved in a file.

As far as I understand it, the HTML head is now rendered completely based on layout XML, it's not a block class anymore. But is there a sensible way to reuse `<head>` rendering without rendering a complete page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found out:

- the head is rendered in the root template `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml`

  ```
  <head <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $headAttributes ?>>
      <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $requireJs ?>
      <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $headContent ?>
      <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $headAdditional ?>
  </head>
  ```

  To use it separated from `<body>` we need to create our own root template with only this part.
- The variables are assigned in `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page::render()` which also renders the root template into a given Response object and inserts the rendered *layout* into the `<body>` element.

  ```
  $this->assign([
      'requireJs' => $requireJs ? $requireJs->toHtml() : null,
      'headContent' => $this->pageConfigRenderer->renderHeadContent(),
      'headAdditional' => $addBlock ? $addBlock->toHtml() : null,
      'htmlAttributes' => $this->pageConfigRenderer->renderElementAttributes($config::ELEMENT_TYPE_HTML),
      'headAttributes' => $this->pageConfigRenderer->renderElementAttributes($config::ELEMENT_TYPE_HEAD),
      'bodyAttributes' => $this->pageConfigRenderer->renderElementAttributes($config::ELEMENT_TYPE_BODY),
      'loaderIcon' => $this->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-2.gif'),
  ]);
  ```

  If we don't want the complete layout and a response, we have to do the same on our own. Using `PageConfigRenderer` should not be a problem.